# Can I heal my mount?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dragonborn

In Skyrim, is there a way to heal my horse while I'm on it? What about a dragon?
I know that if you have the healing hands magic, you can heal a horse while you are not on it, but is there a way to heal them while you are on it (since you can't use magic or staves while on horses)?  I have noticed that even though you can use magic while on a dragon, you cannot use healing magic (including magic to heal yourself).  Is there a way to heal your dragon?

Comment: Unless the page I linked is wrong, it looks like you *can* use certain Restoration spells while riding a dragon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I've seen, it looks like you're only able to heal your horse while you are standing next to it, rather than riding it.

As for healing your dragon, based on the [Healing Hands wikia page](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Healing_Hands), it looks like it **will** work for your dragon mount, since dragons are not listed as exceptions.

> It will not heal undead, atronachs, or Dwemer animunculi.

However, you can't cast it while riding, as it's not listed on the list of spells/shouts you can cast/shout from dragonback [here](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Dragonborn:Dragon_Riding#Combat).

Comment: sounds like it's time to bring out the mod tools again

Answer (score 2):

As stated in both the question and the other answer, you can't heal a horse while riding it because you can't use spells while riding a horse.

As far as riding dragons is concerned, it is possible to heal both it and yourself while riding one by casting Grand Healing. I've done this myself. I play Skyrim using the Legendary Edition patch 1.9 on PC with no mods installed. That includes not using the unofficial patch.

Comment: but does this work with PS4 version, no mods installed?

Comment: I couldn't say for certain. I believe there is very little difference in code nowadays between the likes of legendary edition on PC and the remastered version on PS4 (gameplay wise). With that in mind, it ought to work.

Comment: Where do I get the Grand Healing spell?  I've never seen it...

Comment: It's an expert spell. Colette Marence, the expert Restoration trainer at the College of Winterhold, can sell the tome to you when your Restoration skill is 65 or higher.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll definitely look for that when I get my Restoration that high!